How do I find Loop or Tissue Add On in Preferences?
I can not find neither Loop or Tissue Add On in the preferences tab.
I have the latest Blender 4.2 LTS.  I am going to Edit > Preferences > Add Ons then search for Loop or Tissue and nothing shows up.

Hi. You need to look in Get Extensions, just above Add-ons in the preferences menu. This changed with 4.2. See this link for some info: https://developer.blender.org/docs/release_notes/4.2/#add-ons

Thank you very much.  I appreciate the help.  One more thing.  I downloaded the Loop Tool Add On but when I save it to the Add On and save the preference I don't see it on the tap on the right hand side.  I now see the Tissue tab but not the Loop Tool.

Nevermind. I found it. :-). I had to be in Edit Mode and click the Edit tab and then I can see the Loop Tools option.  Thank you so much for your help. :-)

Find the "Get Extensions" tab in the preferences:

